# Adding scalatags to Play framework project

Tags: playframework, scala.js, scalatags

I have a Play framework project with client and server parts. The client part uses scala.js. I'm trying to use scalatags in the client side script.

In build.sbt for the project, I added `"com.lihaoyi" %% "scalatags" % "0.5.5"` to the libraryDependencies. IntelliJ then gives me correct code completion for scalatags types. The page is the following:

```
package app

import scala.scalajs.js
import org.scalajs.dom
import scalatags.Text.all._

object App extends js.JSApp {
    def main(): Unit = {
        dom.document.getElementById("scalajsShoutOut").innerHTML = h1("Hello").render
    }
}
```

However, when requesting the page I get compiler errors:

```
[error] Referring to non-existent class scalatags.Text$all$
[error]   called from app.App$.main()scala.Unit
[error]   called from scala.scalajs.js.JSApp$class.$$js$exported$meth$main(scala.scalajs.js.JSApp)java.lang.Object
[error]   called from app.App$.$$js$exported$meth$main()java.lang.Object
[error]   called from app.App$.main
[error]   exported to JavaScript with @JSExport
[error] involving instantiated classes:
[error]   app.App$
etc.
```

What other setup is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `%%%` instead of `%%` in the dependencies of a Scala.js project:

```
"com.lihaoyi" %%% "scalatags" % "0.5.5"
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Simple build tool indeed.